# ReactJS syntax and calling a function in JSX

Tags: reactjs

This doesn't work

```
import React , {useContext} from "react"
import {AppContext} from "../AppContext"

function CartItem({item}) {
 
    const {removeFromCart} = useContext(AppContext)

    return (
        <div className="cart-item">
            <i onClick={removeFromCart(item.id)} className="ri-delete-bin-line"></i>
            <img src={item.url} width="130px" />
            <p>$5.99</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartItem
```

But this works

```
import React , {useContext} from "react"
import {AppContext} from "../AppContext"

function CartItem({item}) {
 
    const {removeFromCart} = useContext(AppContext)

    return (
        <div className="cart-item">
            <i onClick={()=>removeFromCart(item.id)} className="ri-delete-bin-line"></i>
            <img src={item.url} width="130px" />
            <p>$5.99</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartItem
```

The difference is in the way we call removeFromCart function, could someone explain the reason for this to happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `onClick` is expected to be assigned  a function *reference*. In example 1, you are calling a function during the render and assigning `onClick` the return value. This will obviously not work. In 2, you are passing `onClick` a reference to an anonymous arrow function that will call `removeFromCart`, so it will work.

Comment: In short - notice the difference between a function *reference* and a function *call*.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <i onClick={removeFromCart(item.id)} className="ri-delete-bin-line"></i>
```

The onClick requires a function refernce rather than calling the function there itself.

```
<i onClick={()=>removeFromCart(item.id)} className="ri-delete-bin-line"></i>
```

Here you are defining an arrow function which is referrred to onClick. So this works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you kinda confuse JSX with HTML syntax. In HTML you do

```
<div onlick="callThisFunction(1)"></div>
```

But in JSX, things are different. Between the `onClick={}` is pure JS code (ideally should be an expression) that will get evaluated inline, and the  value of that expression will be assign to `onClick`.

So if you want to bind to onClick event an event handler function. Then you should put a function between the `{}`. In your case it's an inline arrow function `()=>removeFromCart(item.id)`.

---

**Side note**, I'm not saying calling function inside that braces is always wrong. You can use factory function that returns another function when called. Example:

```
<div onClick={getOnClickHandler()} />
```